# C#/VS2010/Sharepoint Lists connect

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am currently trying to connect a C# program with a Sharepoint. What I have: a Sharepoint URL, Username and a Password, no Sharepoint.dll (client machine, no Microsoft.Sharepoint namespace, so I use Sharepoint Web Services), Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

I followed this tutorial: http://www.scribd.com/doc/8634090/Accessing-SharePoint-Data-Using-C-Without-Running-Code-On-the-SharePoint-Server-Part-1

What I did so far:

added a "Service Reference" to my project with the URL of my Sharepoint like

```
https://.../content/10003194/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
```

and my code:

```
//no TestSP.Lists here...
TestSP.ListsSoapClient cl = new TestSP.ListsSoapClient();
cl.Open();

String listGUID = "A9E7107B-7AF6-42DC-A1A7-6C898D55D23E";
String viewGUID = "684F5F8A-B32E-461C-BD53-677F84A9C101";

//this is where it crashes
System.Xml.Linq.XElement data = cl.GetListItems(listGUID, viewGUID, null, null, "1000", null, "");

IEnumerable<XElement> elements = data.Elements();

foreach (XElement el in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(el);
}
```

it crashes at the specified line with:

**The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM,Basic realm="..."'**

which is most likely because I did not specify a username and password. Various tutorials on the web showed shat the credentials can be set like this:

```
TestSP.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Problem is: there is no `TestSP.Lists`, so I used `TestSP.ListsSoapClient`, which has no `Credentials`, only `ClientCredentials`, which are read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably used the new "Add **Service** Reference", and not "Add **Web** Reference". This creates a wrapper similar to WCF (with the `Client` suffix), and not a Soap based wrapper. You can specify its credentials using:

```
TestSP.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

The "Add Web Reference" is hidden in Visual Studio 2010. If you want, you can [still use it to generate code similar to your tutorial](http://boncode.blogspot.com/2010/07/vs2010-visual-studio-2010-finding-web.html), but the Service Reference should work as well.

See also: [ClientBase<>.ClientCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms553830.aspx)

---

Side note: If all you do is *reading* list items based of a view, you may want to consider using an xml view - [Getting XML Data From a SharePoint List](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2009/05/01/getting-xml-data-from-a-sharepoint-list-the-easy-way.aspx). You can easily get the content by performing a web request. It has some issues with item limit, but it is generally more convenient.

Comment: same error with these credentials, but I used add web reference now and it seems to work, I don't get an "unauthorized" error anymore, now it's another error: `Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.`. but I think thats something else...

Comment: @Eike - Hope I've helped. I've updated the answer with another way of getting your data, for your consideration.